# Regularity of simple ring extensions, subrings and quotients

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a regular UFD of zero characteristic, $I=(p)$ a prime ideal of $R$ and $Q(R)$ the field of fractions of $R$.

1. Assume $R[a]$ is integral and flat over $R$, for some $a \notin Q(R)$. Is it true that $R[a]$ is also regular? If the answer is no (I suspect it is no), what additional conditions are needed to guarantee that $R[a]$ is regular?
   Notice that if $a \in Q(R)$, then $R[a]=R$ (since integral+flat implies faithfully flat, and a faithfully flat extension $A \subseteq B$ with $Q(A)=Q(B)$ implies $A=B$).
2. Assume $R' \subseteq R$ is a noetherian subdomain which is not a UFD, and there exists $r \in R$ integral over $R'$ such that $R'[r]=R$. When $R'$ is also a regular ring? (I do not want to assume that $R' \subseteq R$ is flat).
3. When $R/I$ will be regular? I guess one has to add somewhat restrictive conditions on $p$.

I do not mind if we restrict the first two questions to the case $R=k[x,y]$ and the third question to $R=k[x,y,z]$.
A partial answer will be great too.

Comment: Regular rings were considered for algebraic geometry reasons; translating your questions in terms of algebraic geometry makes them essentially trivial. For 1) and 3), take $R=k[x,y]$, $R[a]=R[z]/(z^2-xy)$, $p=x^3+x^2+y^2$. I don't understand 2): a regular ring is a UFD.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexamples. I apologize for not being clear enough, but what I meant is to find some additional conditions on $R$, $a$, $R'$ and $p$, such that $R[a]$, $R'$ and $R/I$ are regular. (A regular local ring is a UFD, but what if it is not local? I only know it is normal).

Comment: In 2. I meant that $R'$ is a noetherian subdomain of $R$, and $R'$ is not a UFD. In each of the three questions I assume that $R$ is a regular UFD of zero characteristic.

Comment: Then how could $R'$ be regular, if it is not a UFD??

Comment: As far as I know, but I may be missing something, a regular local ring is a UFD (Auslander-Buchsbaum theorem, can be found in Matsumura Theorem 20.3). A regular ring is normal (Matsumura Theorem 19.4). So I do not see any serious problem in my question. (Anyway, I do not mind to assume that $R'$ is not necessarily a UFD).

Comment: Regularity does not imply UFD unless local. For example, take $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/y^2-x^3-1$.